# Will blow off valve cause compressor surge if set to vent 1 psi higher than desired boost?

Tags: turbocharger, tuning

Lets say i set my boost controller at 15 psi of boost, and uses a BOV that has 16 psi spring to minimize boost leak, when i close the throttle the intake pressure spikes above 16 psi for a moment then get vented by BOV, dropping to 15 psi.

Now that the pressure is under 16 psi (15 psi) which is lower than pressure that's required to vent, wont that 15 psi of pressure cause compressor surge?

Comment: Will it be offset by the energy from the turbine? Or the enthalpy change?

Comment: How to offset the turbine?